# Proof of product of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Use the inverse of a 2x2 matrix formula to confirm that:
"The product of two symmetric matrices is symmetric if and only if the matrices commute."
IN THE CASE where the symmetric matrix
$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & d \end{pmatrix}$ is invertible.

Comment: [Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1129053/721644) to a related question from a year later.

Answer (score 1):

$$(AB)^t=B^tA^t\implies \left((AB)^t=AB\iff BA=B^tA^t=AB\right)$$

Comment: What is the link with the inverse? What are you exactly saying? Sorry, I'm bad in math.

Comment: This is a proof which doesn't use the inverse of a $2\times2$ matrix, in fact it's a proof that works for square matrices of any size, invertible or not.