# $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian matrices. Prove that $AB$ is hermitian iff $AB = BA$

Tags: linear-algebra

Completely stuck with this.
I can understand that I have to prove two cases:

1) If $AB$ is hermitian matrix then $AB=BA$

2) IF $AB=BA$ the $AB$ is hermitian matrix.

Comment: What have you tried? What does it mean for a matrix to be Hermitian? What is the Hermitian conjugate of a product of matrices?

Comment: Is one direction easier than the other?

Comment: Closely related, about symmetric rather than Hermitian matrices: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128845/product-of-symmetric-matrices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) $AB=(AB)^H=B^HA^H=BA$.

2) $(AB)^H=(BA)^H=A^HB^H=AB$.